# Log TraceNo for each request in web application using Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a class named `TraceNoGenerator` that works like a Sequence in an Oracle Database; I want to use this class to assign a trace number for each request that comes to my web application to log in a log file. When my application received an error, this trace number will display on a web page so that I can easily find the bug using this trace number in the log file.

How can I do this in Log4j?

Comment: Can't you just use the java.util.logging package?